# How do I take optically faithful videos of glow props in the dark?

Tags: video, recording

I own a small business making LED glow props and though the technology is sound, taking good footage of them in use is proving to be far more difficult than I expected.

I've tried with all sorts of different cameras but they all seem to result in the same thing which is gaps (seems to happen if I shoot in non-interlaced mode) or overlaps (I get this when I shoot in interlaced mode) between frames e.g.

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to combine the frames without the overlap?

Comment: That image doesn't really tell me very much. Is it a lightsaber type of thing that you are waving up and down?

Comment: It is difficult to assess what is going on in that image, but the **shutter speed** of your camera may be a factor: http://vimeo.com/videoschool/lesson/56/frame-rate-vs-shutter-speed-setting-the-record-straight

Comment: it's a light shining up a white cone which is then swung in one direction.. ...like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OwUFh_Fbp4&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 2):

Deciding whether or not to shoot interlaced is really a matter of matching your destination format.  If you're shooting video for the web, you should record it in progressive scan mode.  You *can* record interlaced, and then de-interlace it in software, but this will likely lead to video artifacts, especially considering your subject matter.

I think the picture you posted has misled many commenters into giving you the wrong advice.  Because the picture is blurry, they recommend a faster shutter speed, which *will* sharpen a moving object.  But, given the nature of [the video you linked to](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OwUFh_Fbp4&feature=player_embedded), I think more motion blur will result in a smoother, more natural look.  So try recording progressive, with a slow shutter speed.  This will let more light into the lens, brightening the exposure and making longer motion trails.

Also, try to match the framerate with which you're recording to that of your destination.  If you are recording at 29.97 and vimeo or youtube is playing at 24fps, they're going to introduce some frame blending on their end, which you have no control over, and which is likely to introduce artifacts.